# Asymptotic behaviour of sums of special functions: StruveH and BesselY

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, graphing-functions

In my research I obtained as result for a real function the following expression:

$$u(r) = H_0\left((-1)^{1/3} \, r \right) - Y_0\left((-1)^{1/3} \, r \right) + H_0\left(-  (-1)^{2/3}\, r \right)- Y_0\left(-  (-1)^{2/3}\, r \right)- H_0\left(r \right)- Y_0\left(r \right)
$$

Where $H_0$ is the zeroth order StruveH function and $ Y_0$ is the zeroth order Bessel function of the second kind, and $r$ a real number greater than zero. I was quite happy about my result so i decided to plot it with mathematica and the result is the following:

[image]

The solution starts to behave strangely for large $r$, but i am not sure if this is just Mathematica not properly plotting, or if actually the solution is diverging at large $r$. Is there a way of evaluate such asymptotic behaviour? do you have any reference for that?

Comment: Recall that $K=H-Y$ and use this asymptotic expansions:
http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.6

Comment: It definitely looks like numerical error. You can probably show it rigorously by using the known asymptotics for the [Bessel functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17) and [Struve functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.6).

Comment: how are the third-roots of negatives defined?

Comment: @tired in the summation you also have a -H -Y, how do you treat that?

Comment: If it is numerical error, do Bessel and Struve have any "move" relations like sin and cos families do? Say for example being able to calculate $\cos(x)/x$ from $\cos(x+2\pi)/(x+2\pi)$. If they do maybe that could reduce the numerical error for expansions.

Comment: @mathreadler (-1)^(1/3)= 0.5 +0.866025 i in my definition. However, I am not very familiar with these special functions.

Comment: Playing around with numerics, it looks like the first four terms go to zero exponentially fast (i.e. not oscillatory) until one gets into the numerically-unstable tail (around $r=40$). The oscillation, then, appears to be entirely due to the last two terms; more importantly, Mathematica doesn't seem to run into numerical issues with these two terms. So you may be able to justify focusing on just these last two terms at large $r$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I don't really mind if it's the numeric failing, I just want to be sure it's not an unphysical behaviour of my function.